# Using the relative import mechanism, how to import a module from a parent directory in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a file hierarchy of a python package, "try_from_import", like this:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── fibo.py
└── test
    └── __init__.py
```

Within the directory "test", I cannot import the module fibo.py:

```
In [1]: from .. import fibo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-94aab0998156> in <module>
----> 1 from .. import fibo

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How can I import the module fibo from the folder "test"? I am using python 3.7 on a Mac OS if that matters.

[update] Following the advice in the comments, "do not run python from within the package", I tried to run a file test/test.py which contains "from .. import fibo" from outside the package named "try_from_import". But I still got the error:

```
% python try_from_import/test/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try_from_import/test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .. import fibo
```

Comment: Relative imports are not a directory traversal mechanism. They cannot be used to import anything that could not have been imported with an absolute import.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "absolute import"? Also, what could I do as a work-around if I want to import fibo from the subdirectory test?

Comment: Absolute imports are `import whatever` or `from something_with_no_leading_dot import whatever`.

Comment: Get out of the `test` subdirectory. While you're at it, get out of the parent directory too. You should not execute Python from within a Python package - it messes with the import path.

Comment: I see. You said "You should not execute Python from within a Python package " Do you have reference or PEP? If you put your comments into an answer, I will be glad to accept it, and it'll help others maybe. Thanks in any circumstance.

Comment: Please also see my edits above.  I tried to invoke the python script from outside the package, but the error remains.

Comment: `python -m try_from_import.test.test`

Comment: Thanks! It indeed works. But where can I find doc on the "-m" flag?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m